# Excel VBA Cutting rows from workbook1 and paste it in workbook2

Tags: excel, vba

I've encountered a problems where i can't figure out the problem in the loop  in order to cut it into these desires outcome. i am not good at the looping part but i almost got it, i just need someone to enlighten me with this part.

**Sample Data:**
*Workbook 1*
`A      B    C    D    E<--(header)
 1      2    3    4    5
 1.1    2.1  3.1  4.1  5.1
 1.2    2.2  3.2  4.2  5.2
 1.3    2.3  3.3  4.3  5.3`

*Workbook 2*
`A       B       C      D        E<--(header)
Apple   Boy     Cat     Dog     Ele
Apple1  Boy1    Cat1    Dog1    Ele1
Apple2  Boy2    Cat2    Dog2    Ele2
Apple3  Boy3    Cat3    Dog3    Ele3`

*Desire Output in Workbook2:*
`A       B       C      D        E<--(header)
Apple   Boy     Cat     Dog     Ele
1        2       3       4       5
Apple1  Boy1    Cat1    Dog1    Ele1
1.1      2.1     3.1     4.1     5.1
Apple2  Boy2    Cat2    Dog2    Ele2
1.2      2.2     3.2     4.2     5.2 
Apple3  Boy3    Cat3    Dog3    Ele3
1.3      2.3     3.3     4.3     5.3`

**Here are my codes.**

```
 Sub foo()
 Dim x As Workbook
 Dim y As Workbook
 Dim X1 As Worksheet

 Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\DON\My     Documents\testingmacro2.xlsx")   <----Workbook 1

 Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\DON\My Documents\testingmacro3.xlsx")   <----Workbook 2  

Set X1 = x.Sheets(2)       <----Workbook 1
Set Y1 = y.Sheets(1)       <----Workbook 2

For i = 2 To 1000

If X1.Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
   Exit For
   End If

    For j = 1 To 1000 Step 5   (this is the part where i am having problems to get the desires outcome)


        If Y1.Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then 
            Exit For
            Else

            X1.Cells(i, j).Resize(, 5).Cut
            i = i + 1
            Y1.Range("A" & i).Insert xlShiftDown
            End If

            Next

       Next

x.Close
y.Close True

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @RawrPlus for the solutions, i did amend some of the parts in order to make it exactly what i want. Here are my answers.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub table_to_table()
'Declaration
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\lye.yan.nian\My Documents\testingmacro2.xlsx")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\lye.yan.nian\My Documents\testingmacro3.xlsx")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Test2")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Test1")

Dim res_lr As Long
Dim lr2 As Long
lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Dim copyrange As Range
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To lr2


'Set copyrange = ws2.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6))
Set copyrange = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(i, 1), ws2.Cells(i, 5))
copyrange.Copy

res_lr = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox res_lr
ws2.Range(Cells(res_lr + 1, 8), Cells(res_lr + 1, 12)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues /* This is the part where i make changes */

'Set copyrange = ws1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6))
Set copyrange = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Cells(i, 5)) 
copyrange.Copy

ws2.Range(Cells(res_lr + 2, 8), Cells(res_lr + 2, 12)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues /* This is the part where i make changes */

Next i

wb1.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA to do that.

step 1. add a temp column in workbook 1 and workbook 2
[image]

step 2. copy workbook 1 and special-paste to workbook 2 with value
[image]

step 3. sort temp column in workbook 2 then delete the temp column
[image]

Comment: i know, but i need this because i have a lot of workbook that requires this function.

Answer (score 1):

You're on a good path, but there are some small errors.

1. You should always use `Option Explicit`, this helps you prevent small typographical errors, missing declarations and so on. eg. it would have prevented missing `Dim` declaration for `Y1`
2. You don't have to loop through set rows (eg. `2 To 1000`) Not only it's ineffective, but unnecessary. You can detect the last  actively used row of data.
3. You shouldn't do `i = i + 1` inside your `for` loop. In VBA `for` loop by default already has a autoincrementation (`++`) inbuilt. If you wish to change it, change it with the declaration of the `for` loop

   eg. `for i = 1 To 1000 Step 2` (does `i = i + 2`). Manipulating with this internally can cause a lot of unexpected result and this behaviour should be reserved for the `Do While/Until` loop where you don't directly manipulate with it.
4. At the end you have `x.Close` and then `y.Close True` one of which is obviously not valid syntax.
5. Technically not an error, but a good coding practice. Don't use vague variable names like `x` for Workbooks and `x1` for Worksheets. Especially in larger programs being read by somebody else this will cause unnecessary confusion. Or worse yet, even yourself, if you check it 4 years down the line.

---

**Now to the actual answer:**

> This works under presumption  `tbl1` is in columns `(2-6)`, `tbl2` in `(2-6)` and the `result` in `(8-12)`

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub table_to_table()
 'Declaration
 Dim wb1 As Workbook
 Dim wb2 As Workbook
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet
 Dim ws2 As Worksheet
 Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\DON\My Documents\testingmacro2.xlsx")
 Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\DON\My Documents\testingmacro3.xlsx")
 Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Name") 'better to use names instead of indices
 Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Another name") 'if you add/remove sheets, index change occurs

 Dim res_lr As Long
 Dim lr2 As Long
 lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in ws2

 Dim copyrange As Range
 Dim i As Long
 For i = 2 To lr2
    ' we only loop once, for all values in tbl2
    ' once we run out of things to add, there's no point looping further
    ' furthermore, it looks like tbl1 and tbl2 both begin on same row
      so we can loop through same value
    Set copyrange = ws2.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6)).Copy
    res_lr = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in result tbl
    ws2.Range(Cells(res_lr, 8), Cells(res_lr, 12)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Set copyrange = ws1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6)).Copy
    ' if tbl2 began in another range, simply change to i + start of data row
    ws2.Range(Cells(res_lr + 1, 8), Cells(res_lr + 1, 12)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

 Next i

 wb1.Close 'closes wb1 after looping, i'd leave wb2 open to display the results

End Sub
```

Comment: I am encountering object required on this line "Set copyrange = ws2.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6)).Copy", i tried to debug, but not sure what's the problem in this line.

Comment: @Nian have you changed the sheet names to fit yours?

Comment: Yes i did, but still  encountered the same problem.

Comment: I've tested to extract all those data using msgbox function and through the ws1 and ws2 variable, yes i can get all the data from the two different workbook

Comment: So it's solved now? Sorry I'm kind of confused from your comments. If not, please specify what exactly is going wrong. Because that line of code in comments should be perfectly valid

Comment: Nope, it's not solved,  still trying on debugging the problem. I will attached the problems in illustrations. Link: https://imgur.com/a/wGglCi8. The line which highlighted in yellow color is where it got the error '424' object required.