# Excel VBA run-time Error '424' Object Required

Tags: vba, excel

I've encountered a problem run-time Error '424' object required.
This is the solution i've acquired from my previous post, after spending some time to troubleshoot, i still can't solve it. Thanks to @rawrplus for the solution and I am still learning Excel vba.

***Link:*** [Excel VBA Cutting rows from workbook1 and paste it in workbook2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650643/excel-vba-cutting-rows-from-workbook1-and-paste-it-in-workbook2/51653150?noredirect=1#comment90365313_51653150)

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub table_to_table()
'Declaration
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\lye.yan.nian\My  Documents\testingmacro2.xlsx")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\lye.yan.nian\My Documents\testingmacro3.xlsx")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Test2")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Test1")

Dim res_lr As Long
Dim lr2 As Long
lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row


MsgBox lr2   /* Testing is done as i can get this value */

Dim r As Range, ary
Set r = ws1.Application.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 6)) /* Tested working as i can get this value too*/
ary = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r.Value))
MsgBox Join(ary, " ")


Dim copyrange As Range
Dim i As Long /* This is declared */
For i = 2 To lr2

MsgBox i /* i did some testing on this and removed the below code */
Set copyrange = ws2.Application.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6)).Copy /* This is the part where i got the error i can't figure out why*/ 

res_lr = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
ws2.Range(Cells(res_lr, 8), Cells(res_lr, 12)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Set copyrange = ws1.Application.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6)).Copy

ws2.Range(Cells(res_lr + 1, 8), Cells(res_lr + 1, 12)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next i

wb1.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to qualify `Cells` and `Rows` with the worksheet they are referring to otherwise you're implicitly using the `ActiveSheet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set copyrange = ws2.Application.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6)).Copy
```

[`Range.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) does not return a `Range` object reference that you can assign to a `Range` object variable. It's a member method that takes the contents of a range, and copies it into the clipboard.

Your `copyrange` isn't the result of the `.Copy` operation, it's the result of a `ws2.Application.Range(...)` call... which is malformed.

This *might* fix it<sup>1</sup>:

```
Set copyrange = ws2.Application.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6))
copyrange.Copy
```

....and this is what you probably *meant* to be doing:

```
Set copyrange = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(i, 2), ws2.Cells(i, 6))
copyrange.Copy
```

---

<sup>1</sup> it's bad code, because you have an explicit `Worksheet` reference (`ws2`), and from there you go to `Application` to grab whatever worksheet is currently active, and work off that - so you *think* you're working off `ws2` when in reality you're working off whatever `ActiveSheet` currently happens to be. Same with the unqualified `Cells` calls, which implicitly refer to `Application.ActiveSheet.Cells`.

Comment: Thank you so much man, it worked. Now i learnt something, i will make that changes to my code, thanks for the advice once again.

Comment: Mathieu, can you clarify a little more? Is it bad because using `Application.Range` bypasses the Workbook Object and Worksheet Object, thus the Range will be selected on which ever worksheet is currently active?

Comment: @GMalc `Application.Range` is implicitly `Application.ActiveSheet.Range`. `Range` as a member call, is always a member of a `Worksheet` object. Good code makes that `Worksheet` explicit ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the word `set` on the line where it throws error. 
Example: `set x = 'something`

Comment: "Set copyrange = ws2.Application.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6)).Copy" Set has been used in this line

Comment: May i know what brackets are you talking about? Can you show me?